# How to keep the view specific heading in the navigation on page refresh in Angular 2

Tags: angular, local-storage

I am new to Angular 2. I have a navigation service which works perfectly fine in determining the headings for my app but only when the app is not refreshed in an Angular 2 app.

1.How I can keep the headings of different views in my app on page refresh? I am trying to do that with local storage. I am able to set the the value for local storage variables. I want to get the value from local storage only on page refresh and using forward or back button. Otherwise I want my local storage be cleared.
2. How I can clear the local storage after I have achieved my desired functionality.

Inside the main component

```
ngOnInit() {
localStorage.setItem('defaultNavHeading', this.defaultNavHeading);
localStorage.setItem('processDetailsHeading', this.processDetailsHeading);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may clear local storage by applying any of these following code

localStorage.clear();
 or
localStorage.removeItem("localStorage ");
 or
window.localStorage.clear();